# Why is my root URL serving up a 404 under Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, directoryindex

My virtual host file is below. There is a directory /home/jonathan/cats/, and it contains an index.html. And it is world-readable, with the directory being world-executable. (Other VirtualHosts exist on the same host nicely.)

I'd like to know for future reference what the problem is here so I can recognize it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName cats.stornge.com
ServerAlias cats.jonathanhayward.com, www.cats.jonathanhayward.com

    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/cats
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/jonathan/cats>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? If so you might need to set SELinux web permissions to the directory: `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/jonathan/cats`

Comment: No; it's a mainstream Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the bouncy balls page your 404?

Comment: I get a page with three animated balls from www.cat.jonathanhayward.com, and cats.stornge.com but what looks like your homepage from cats.jonathonhayward.com, where are you accessing your page from?

Comment: Is the a snippet of your virtual host file? The virtual host should end with </VirtualHost>

Comment: The file ends with /VirtualHost.

Comment: The 404 page is a moping computer at http://jonathanscorner.com/missing.html . I get my homepage when I load http://www.cat.jonathanhayward.com/ , and an error page accessing stornge.com. This was damage from moving between servers, and I've set the DNS entry to point to the original webpage.

Comment: @Jonathan Hayward The comma in the ServerAlias is not necessary.. it may actually be harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this, you should not put commas in the `ServerAlias` directive, the only divider accepted is a space, so it should be:

`ServerAlias cats.jonathanhayward.com www.cats.jonathanhayward.com`

Comment: Thank you; I saw your comment and was going to ask you to restate your response as an answer. Upvoted and accepted with pleasure.

Comment: Glad to have been of assistance!